# Why Angular 4 ngModel changes another variables?

Tags: angular

I've found funny bug in Angular 4 ngModel.
Component:

```
this.restService.getProduct(this._id).subscribe(
   response => {
     this.product = response;
     this.productCategory = response.category;
...
```

Template:

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "productCategory._id" class="form-control form-
control-sm" id="category">
    <option *ngFor="let category of existedCategories | orderBy: 'name'" 
    value="{{category._id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
```

When I change ngModel value of productCategory._id in template, value of this.product.category._id changes too. And this check returns false:

```
if (this.product.category._id !== this.productCategory._id) {
 observables.push(
  this.restService.changeProductCategory(this.product.category._id, 
  this.productCategory._id, this.product._id));
}
```

I found some solution for bypassing this:

```
this.restService.getProduct(this._id).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.product = response;
    const resp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    this.productCategory = resp.category;
```

But still don't understand why it happens.

Comment: You are databinding to the wrong property if that is what you want. `[(ngModel)] = "productCategory._id"` binds to `this.productCategory._id`, you could bind to `product.category._id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because productCategory referring to the same place in memory that product.category does.

It is not the Angular 4 bug. It's how reference types works. I'm attaching link for study: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 0):

Because you make a reference. If you need another behavior, you have to do clone.
In lodash there is cloneDeep.